# Two Webfonts (Google & Typekit) One as Fallback, how to avoid calls?

Tags: javascript, css, web, webfonts

Right now we have one font which is used the main font and comes from Typekit. We want to have a fallback from Google Webfonts. The Typekit Font is implemented with kit js.

Our problem right now is that we want to avoid calls to the different CDNs. We did not want to load two different fontsets. The font-stack would be look like that:

"Typekit Font", Google Font, Arial, sans-serif ....

My question is just really easy to answer. Is there an easy way to avoid this calls and to check out if the main font is not available? And load the other?

I am not a developer but I have handle with one and he says this can't be done. Just need some food for this developer to go on and do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a stretch, but you can probably use typekit's [Font Events](http://blog.typekit.com/2010/11/11/font-events-using-javascript-callbacks/) to conditionally load the Google Web Font if your typekit font emits an "inactive" event. The issue with this is that it may take up to 5 seconds for your font to "timeout", and your user will be left in the lurch while this process is happening.

I'd really suggest *not* doing this, and just using a decent CSS fallback.

That said, this JS should be a start (albeit an ugly one):

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/vio0gns.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  try {

  var config = {
      scriptTimeout: 3000 // tweak as necessary
    };

    Typekit.load({
      loading: function() {

      },
      active: function() {

      },
      inactive: function() {
         console.log('Font Timed Out');
         WebFontConfig = {
           google: { families: [ 'Balthazar::latin' ] }
         };
         (function() {
           var wf = document.createElement('script');
           wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
             '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
           wf.type = 'text/javascript';
           wf.async = 'true';
           var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
         })(); 
      }
    })
  } catch(e) {}

</script>
```

<kbd>[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/NickTomlin/pen/AoGhu)</kbd>  (the google font should load after 3-5 secounds)

Answer (score 0):

You could first detect browser type using JavaScript, then load a set of CSS styles, each one containing a separate font family.  Media queries may also work.  Sorry, too many examples are out there to start.